# Resource path without specifying ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want to render a partial if my path is on a specific resource, but I don't want to indicate the ID of the resource.

I want to load meta data tags held in a partial between my `<head>` tags if the path is on any video resource:

```
<head>
  <%= render 'layouts/partial_name' if request.fullpath == video_path(params[:id]) %>
</head>
```

This only works, though, if I've requested a video resource, e.g., `'/videos/92'`.

Comment: `if request.fullpath =~ /\A\/videos/`

Comment: We don't need to know if you're new at something. A good question is a good question, no matter what. Do your due-diligence, and search SO and Google before you ask and then, if you haven't found out what you want to know, ask away. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, the Tin Man. Nice edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `request.full_path.starts_with? videos_path`, or `request.full_path =~ /^\/video/`.

However, there's a better way to do this. In your layout:

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

In the view where you want to add meta tags:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<%= render :partial => 'meta_tags' %>
<% end %>
<!-- ... -->
```

This usage is the [canonical example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method) for the `content_for` method.

Comment: Works like a charm, willglynn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for...

```
<%= render 'layouts/partial_name' if params[:controller] == "videos"  && params[:action] == "show" %>
```

Comment: I like this, but the partial would be loaded for all methods in the videos controller, including index, edit, new, etc. I'm referencing variables in the meta tags, so it errors out. It doesn't look like `if params[:controller] == "videos#show"` registers.

Comment: There's also a params[: action]

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you would want a custom layout for the controller responsible for the videos resource. More about layout can been learned at this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts.

For a quick and dirty (very very dirty) solution you can check if request.fullpath contains the "videos" string. eg.

```
<%= render 'layouts/partial_name' if request.fullpath =~ /videos/ %>
```

Comment: Why should he make a separate layout just to add something to the `<head>`?

Comment: Presumably if he wants to render a specific partial in the head section on video pages, then there must be something different about the page itself. I'm guessing the partial is either a stylesheet or js? Then it probably would make more sense to introduce a new layout.

Comment: He says "I want to load meta data tags", presumably `<meta name="keywords">` and `"description"`.

Comment: @willglynn point taken. :) Somehow I missed the meta tags part.

Comment: nan and willglynn, this is great feedback. I could have emphasized my use of meta tags more.